# Pyinstaller packing of D-tale

Tags: python, cmd, pyinstaller, eda

I'm trying to use pyinstaller (latest version) to package D-table as an EXE file, but I'm getting this error:

> FileNotFoundError: No such file of directory: ...\dash_colorscales\metadata.json.** 
> FileNotFoundError: No such file of directory: ...\dtale\translations.

I have tried to use a hook file as below, but still it didn't work.

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files, collect_submodules
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('dtale')
datas = collect_data_files('dtale', include_py_files=True)
```

How can I fix this?

Here is my *main.py* file:

```
import dtale

if name == 'main':
    dtale.show().open_browser()
    app = dtale.app.build_app(reaper_on=False)
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Comment: Re *"D-table"*? Do you mean *"D-tale"*?

Comment: What is this *"D-tale"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add all of the `json` and `js` files from the `dash_daq` and `dash_colorscales` as data with the compiled contents.

These are the steps I took to compile and run the application.

1. Open a new directory and `cd` into it.
2. Create a clean virtual env with `python -m venv venv` and activate it with `venv\scripts\activate`
3. Install dependencies with `pip install dtale pyinstaller`
4. I copied the example code from the dtale GitHub page into a `main.py` file

   `main.py`

   ```
   import dtale
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.DataFrame([dict(a=1,b=2,c=3)])
   d = dtale.show(df, subprocess=False)
   tmp = d.data.copy()
   tmp['d'] = 4
   d.kill()
   d.open_browser()
   dtale.instances()
   ```
5. Run `pyinstaller -F --collect-all dtale main.py`
6. Inside of the created `.spec` file, add the following lines at the top.

   ```
   # -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
   from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all
   import os

   dash_daq = "./venv/Lib/site-packages/dash_daq/"
   datas = [
       ('./venv/Lib/site-packages/dash_colorscales/metadata.json', './dash_colorscales/'),
       ('./venv/Lib/site-packages/dash_colorscales/bundle.js', './dash_colorscales/')]
   for filename in os.listdir(dash_daq):
       if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] in [".js", ".json"]:
           filepath = os.path.join(dash_daq, filename)
           datas.append((filepath, "./dash_daq/"))

   binaries = []
   hiddenimports = []
   tmp_ret = collect_all('dtale')
   datas += tmp_ret[0]; binaries += tmp_ret[1]; hiddenimports += tmp_ret[2]

   block_cipher = None
   ```
7. Run `pyinstaller main.spec`
8. Run `dist/main.exe`

And Bob’s your uncle.

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '...\\dtale\\translations'

This was the error I am still getting.

Comment: Thanks Alexander! I think I'm much closer but still getting this error: 9882 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement six from package dtale. 9882 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement cycler from package dtale. 9882 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement beautifulsoup4 from package dtale. 9882 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement scikit-learn from package dtale. 
But I am able to see these modules in my site-packages folder.. And for the Step 6, I should be pasting that whole section above the codes for a, pyz and exe?

Comment: @Milleon  Then you did something wrong or didn't follow the steps in my example exactly

Comment: I followed it exactly. 
Can you clarify Step 6? Maybe this was where I made a mistake. Do I replace the whole .SPEC file or which lines do I specifically add/where?

Comment: @Milleon  No you leave your spec file exactly the way it is, but add all the lines in step 6 at the top.  except for maybe the last one, since it would probably be duplicate.  In other words, copy everything except `block_cipher = None` at the top of your .spec file

Comment: I am using this as my main.py, as I want it to run on a localhost continuously:

`
import dtale

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dtale.show().open_browser()
    app = dtale.app.build_app(reaper_on=False)
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
`

Comment: 11720 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement cycler from package dtale.
11720 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement six from package dtale.
11720 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement beautifulsoup4 from package dtale.
11720 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement scikit-learn from package dtale.
11728 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement flask-ngrok from package dtale.

Also, I see these modules in the site-packages folder but when I run the .SPEC file it says otherwise.

Comment: then you didn't activate your virtual enviornment... Sorry that might be my bad actually, I assumed you knew what a virtual environment was...  take another look at instruction number 2... I edited it to add the command to activate the virtual env

Comment: I did actually. I just retried it again from scratch, and I'm getting this error when running  step 4.. Can you you try with my main.py content in the comment above? Thanks.

**
OSError: [WinError 4393] The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid: '...\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\plotly\\validators\\layout\\template'
**

Comment: @Milleon  Edit your question and include the contents of your main.py at the end of your question

Comment: If you have a working .exe using my main.py contents, could you share it with me through a link to download?

Comment: Ok added my main.py in the question. Thanks!

Comment: okay. give me a couple minutes.

Comment: DId you try using the script in my example?

Comment: Here is a literal screen recording from start to finish... https://file.io/jW01H1YeBwSn

Comment: Thank you so much for going all the way to help me out, really appreciate what you did. Would upvote you x100 if that is possible.

Even though it is working now for me, I honestly don't know what was the reason why it wasn't working before. The steps look identical, except that I was doing all steps 5 & 7 in CMD while following your video I did it in VS Code..